# AngularJS $animate.addClass requires $timeout

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm having some unexpected behaviour where the $animate service's addClass method is not adding the appropriate -add and -add-active classes.

The same use of the service, wrapped in a $timeout, seems to work as expected:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3sFGp4y2WGA0HReIglR3?p=preview

Obviously, using unnecessary $timeouts is something I would like to avoid.

Am I missing something, or using the service incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

This may be way out of the ballpark of correct answers... because I've never used `ngAnimate` personally (I did see a presentation on it once though). However, I think it's due to the fact that you haven't waited for your image to load, which seems to be the purpose of this directive. The `$timeout` may give you enough time in this example to induce the animation on the correct DOM element, but may not always be correct. I believe that you should be waiting for the 'load' event on the image to use the `.addClass` functionality... which in this case actually turns out to be more or less the same amount of code you originally posted. The thing is that this approach will ensure that the DOM element exists, and the image has fully loaded on the page:

```
element.on('load', function() {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    $animate.addClass(element, 'preloaded', function() {
      console.log('Animation finished!');
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the DOM element be ready in the link function? Removing the img loading requirement from the problem, and simply applying it to the div:
http://plnkr.co/edit/aZ30auynbfdTCbedwpei?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens, but I've noticed that Angular needs to digest somehow before triggering an animation, usually with $timeout. Even directives that should automatically start an animation, like ngClass or ngRepeat, seem to require a timeout if they are not triggered by an event.

So this will work without a timeout:

```
return function (scope, element, attr) {
  scope.addPreloadClick = function() {
    $animate.addClass(element, 'preloaded');
  };
  scope.removePreloadClick = function() {
    $animate.removeClass(element, 'preloaded');
  };
};
```

Updated Plunk using ngClass and ngClick
http://plnkr.co/edit/qLFgCc0XDGJT4e7ampUW?p=preview